# Swift SourceKitService Crashed

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, crash, xcode6

I have a Swift project using Core Data and the generated code for `saveContext()` is causing Xcode to crash with the SourceKitService Crashed error. When I comment it out the error stops, and it seems to be `self.managedObjectContext` which is causing the error. I have commented out my code so it is like a new project but its still crashing. Thanks

(Xcode 6.0.1)

```
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
        }
    }
}
```

I made a new project and copied my code across, and the new project is fine (and exactly the same) so I have reported this to apple as a potential bug.

Thanks

Update:

Found this to make things a little easier :)

https://github.com/kattrali/deriveddata-exterminator

Comment: It is a xcode bug. You should report to Apple

Comment: can you paste the entire code here?

Comment: Upgrade to the Xcode 6.1 beta. This fixes it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I would work on various projects and continually get this error, sometimes to the point where Xcode became unusable.  I eventually solved the problem by quitting Xcode, emptying out the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder, and then reopening the project.

Comment: So this worked for me as well.  What's interesting is that just clearing out the derived data through Xcode is not enough.  completely blowing away the contents of the directory is what did the trick.

Comment: Still seeing the same issue in XCode 6.1... and same solution.

Comment: Thinking about adding this as a cronjob to fire every minute, as XCode 6 keeps spamming me with this error...

Comment: The error still persist after emptying the entire folder...for xcode 6.0.1.

Comment: i hope xcode will be suite for swift one day.Auto completion does not  even work properly this sourcekitservice crash. it just nerves!

Comment: Did that already multiple times but the issue remains the same. Tried it with Xcode 6.0 and Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: I am on XCode 6.1 and after emptying out the content of that folder and reopen the project, it still crashes for no reason

Comment: I am on XCode 6.2 and after emptying out the content of that folder and reopen the project, it still crashes for no reason when I try to use the "Find and Replace tool" in Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score -2):

Apple solve this crash Version: 6.1.1

What's New in Version 6.1.1

Includes SDKs for OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and iOS 8.1

```
• Fixes common causes of SourceKit crashes when working with Swift
• Additional bug fixes and stability improvements
```

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

also you can solve this using delete your project from following path

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: This would be great news if it was actually true!

Comment: I'm running 6.1.1 but I'm still receiving this crash ALL THE TIME.

Comment: No, it is not fixed. I downloaded this minor update just because Apple said they fixed this bug.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra and Rob I am facing same problem in Facebook.framework in facebook sdk, but in Xcode 6.1.1 its working..

Comment: I am on XCode 6.2 and after emptying out the content of that folder and reopen the project, it still crashes for no reason when I try to use the "Find and Replace tool" in Xcode 6.2.