# SourceKitService Crashed

Tags: xcode, swift

Sometimes I have an issue with Xcode 6.0.1 where the error "SourceKitService Crashed Crashlog generated in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports" is popping up and all syntax highlighting is gone in Swift. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have this problem with Xcode 6.1 (release, not GM).

There a few "magic" solutions that works temporarily, but require a restart. There is quick fix that seems to hold (and does not require a complete restart).

Delete the **content** of: DerivedData/ModuleCache

(Full path: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache)

Comment: I owe you a gift next Xmas.

Comment: @bauerMusic  Tried that multiple times but not working for me. Tried it with Xcode 6.0 and then Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: @RohitGoyal I found XCode 6.1.1, which was supposed to fix this issue has this problem sticking harder. I have this issue in much less frequency however. It use to be unworkable, now it's just annoying. Cleaning the project could help.

Comment: @bauerMusic It's never going away in my case. I am not able to make a build whenever i try to I get these 2 errors. 
/Users/MY_PROJECT/AppDelegate.swift:11:1: 'UIApplicationMain' class must conform to the 'UIApplicationDelegate' protocol
at UIApplicationMain 
in my AppDelegate.h file

and this 

Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: @RohitGoyal Seems your problem involves different elements. I suggest opening a new question with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Xcode and you cannot do much about it.

Update to Xcode 6.2 Beta 1 or higher if you want as the situation improved there. Still happening occasionally though.

Comment: Sadly, it's still happening in shipped 6.1.

Comment: Actually, I just was working in a class and got it to crash repeatedly. Trying to diagnose which statement was causing the issue, I came across this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26230440/1080311) and cleared out the derived data folder.  Things have worked without issue since.

Comment: 6.2 GM doesn't exist yet (not even sure if at the point of your last edit 6.2 beta existed) you wrote this for readers in the "future" under the assumption 6.2 would improve: -1

Comment: @Ixx I actually meant beta, not GM. And Beta 2 is the version I'm currently using. I just write that the situation is improved, not fixed. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Try emptying the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My project started crashing SKS several times per minute recently, and none of the voodoo was working anymore.

My workaround—which is not going to last into later, more-complex phases—is to create a dummy project target within my current project (and select it as active). I add the file I'm working on to the dummy target, REMOVING the file from its proper targets temporarily.

Entails a lot of fiddling with target membership, but I am NOT nostalgic for the days of writing tons of code with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such an issue. Source kit service was using 10 gb of usage. Swift process in activity monitor reaches over 6 GB usage. I was using following code:

var details : [String : Any] = ["1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10, "11":11, "12":12, "13":13, "14":14, "15":15, "16":16]

I have changed code to following to solve this issue:

var details : [String : Any] = [:]

details["1"] = 1

details["2"] = 2

details["3"] = 3

details["4"] = 4

details["5"] = 5

details["6"] = 6

details["7"] = 7

details["8"] = 8

details["9"] = 9

details["10"] = 10

details["11"] = 11

details["12"] = 12

details["13"] = 13

details["14"] = 14

details["15"] = 15

details["16"] = 16