# SourceKitService taking up to 200% of CPU

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I just updated to Xcode 12.5.1, and now my SourceKitService is taking insanely high amounts of my CPU whenever I edit a specific file. After editing this file to any extent my CPU usage jumps through the roof, and basic services such as code completion stop working. I've already tried most of the solutions online about this issue, and nothing is helping. Does anyone have any ideas for this? Thanks.

I'll just put all of the file's code in here, because I'm not sure where the issue might originate.

```
//
//  ScheduleView.swift
//  ClassWidget
//
//  Created by Ben K on 6/17/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ScheduleView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @ObservedObject var schedule: Schedule
    @State private var showingAddPeriod = false
    @State private var showingEditPeriod = false
    @State private var editPeriod: Period?
    @State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive
    
    @State private var showingSettings = false
    @State private var showingPreview = false
    
    @State private var showingWarning = false
    @State private var warningPeriod: Period?
    
    var timeFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .none
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("\(editPeriod?.uName ?? "")")
                .hidden()
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Classes")) {
                    if !schedule.periods.isEmpty {
                        ForEach(schedule.periods) { period in
                            Button(action: { editPeriod = period; isEditMode = .inactive; showingEditPeriod = true }) {
                                HStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text(timeFormatter.string(from: period.uStart))
                                        Text("to")
                                        Text(timeFormatter.string(from: period.uEnd))
                                    }
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                    .padding(6)
                                    
                                    Divider()
                                        .frame(height: 35)
                                        .padding(.trailing)
                                    
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text(period.uName)
                                        
                                        if period.uTeacher != "" && period.uRoom != "" {
                                            Text("\(period.uTeacher) • \(period.uRoom)")
                                                .font(.caption)
                                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                        } else if period.uTeacher != "" {
                                            Text("\(period.uTeacher)")
                                                .font(.caption)
                                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                        } else if period.uRoom != "" {
                                            Text("\(period.uRoom)")
                                                .font(.caption)
                                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                        .opacity(0.5)
                                }
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: delete)
                    } else {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("No classes yet")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("Start adding classes to create this schedule!")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .italic()
                        }
                        .padding(8)
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        showingSettings = true
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Settings")
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                .opacity(0.5)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                }
                
                Button("Preview Widget") {
                    showingPreview = true
                }
                
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        }
        .navigationTitle(schedule.uName)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            showingAddPeriod = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus").padding([.vertical, .leading])
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddPeriod) {
            AddPeriod(schedule: schedule)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
        }
        /*.sheet(isPresented: $showingEditPeriod) {
            if let period = editPeriod {
                AddPeriod(period: period)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
            }
        }*/
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingEditPeriod, onDismiss: dismissedSheet) {
            if let period = editPeriod {
                AddPeriod(period: period)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingSettings) {
            ScheduleSettingsView(schedule: schedule)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingPreview) {
            PreviewWidget(schedule: schedule)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingWarning) {
            Alert(title: Text("Delete \(warningPeriod?.uName ?? "")"), message: Text("Are you sure?"), primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                try? moc.save()
            }, secondaryButton: .cancel() {
                if let period = warningPeriod {
                    readdPeriod(period: period)
                }
            })
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
        
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            warningPeriod = schedule.periods[offset]
            moc.delete(schedule.periods[offset])
            showingWarning = true
        }
    }
    
    func readdPeriod(period: Period) {
        let newPeriod = Period(period: period, context: moc)
        newPeriod.schedule = schedule
        try? moc.save()
    }
    
    func dismissedSheet() {
        schedule.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}


struct ScheduleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    
    static var previews: some View {
        let schedule = Schedule(name: "Example Schedule", number: 0, context: moc)
        
        NavigationView {
            ScheduleView(schedule: schedule)//.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post ur code

Comment: Okay, just added the code. Sorry if its badly written, I'm new to this lol

Comment: Your code has a long way to go before it is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. By cleaning it up some and replicating the issue in a clean project you might find the trigger. If you do you can, report to Apple. Stat by commenting out features.

Comment: For people asking about posting code, can you explain why you think that including the code is important here and what you could conclude from reading the code that could possibly explain why the SourceKitService process behaves this way? I am seriously interested since I also am experiencing issues with this service.

Comment: For me to see if I can replicate. So far, I'm far from replicating but I notice a few things such as using `.primary`, etc. Do they have a `Color` extension for it or are they somehow tapping into Xcode 13 iOS 15 `.primary`. Also, those `init` for the CoreData objects are questionable. I don't know why it behaves this way but cleaning build sometimes works and I have had my CPU/SourceKitService go high over SwiftUI intricacies and the dreaded "took to long to compile" message. There was a tweet I saw a while a back when I was searching that said it was because of a $ that was missing.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Here is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295799/sourcekitservice-crashed?rq=1) that says it was the manner in which they built a dictionary. That is why I added with my comment that they should comment out sections to see if they find a trigger.

Comment: @lorem ipsum `.primary` is a part of Color, I believe. It returns white/black based on the phone's color mode. I think the issue has something to do with the modifiers on the `ZStack`. When I comment out the bottom three modifiers (excluding `.environment`), it begins working again, but only when all of them are commented out together. I'm not sure where to go from here, I have no idea why these modifiers are causing this.

Comment: @loremipsum that is one answer with no upvotes that says that all other talk about this being an issue with Xcode so I am skeptical

Comment: @Tortuga Have you tried moving the modifiers to the Views that activate them? Like the `Button` that triggers `showingAddPeriod`. On iPad it is visible that they attach themselves to the `View` it might make a difference to not have them all attached to the `ZStack`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I get it. It is such a vague thing but I think it is plausible. If it was an Xcode issue everybody would have it, I think. Maybe we will narrow down this one, it seems like we might be getting close. Maybe you will narrow down yours if you start commenting out portions of code.

Comment: @lorem ipsum So far, it seems like that worked! I'm not sure why, but so far its back to normal. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tortuga I'm glad it helped. I added an answer so maybe somebody else will consider syntax when this happens. If you don't mind accepting it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code there seems to be a lot going on but along with the other solutions you will find in SO,

It is helpful to start commenting out portions of your code to try and narrow down a syntax issue that might be causing it.

Per out conversation in the comments the issue was caused by the multiple view modifiers that were attached to your `ZStack` moving them to the views that activated them has so far resolved it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering now if having multiple `.sheet` and `.fullScreenCover` modifiers had anything to do with it, because it was only the bottom two, plus the `.alert` modifiers that seemed to cause this.

Comment: No idea the only thing I can come up with is that maybe it was trying to attach them to all the Views within since it is a ViewModifier. But, that is just a guess. If we could replicate in another project we would be able to dissect. I still haven’t had the issue in my Macbook but I am not using the new release XCode yet. I always wait a few days to update. I don’t see it in XCode 13 either so if it is a bug it might get resolved.

Comment: Hopefully. Before I fixed this, I downgraded to 12.5 and it was still happening. What's weird is that I don't remember changing anything between it working on 12.5 and it breaking on 12.5.1, so I really don't know what's up with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compiler type-checking engine failure, aka

> compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time;
> try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

For some reason it fails silently and causes SourceKitService and swift-frontend to leak.

You need to simplify you view by moving logically discrete parts of the view into separate helper vars/funcs or structs.